# Django post_save signal acts like pre_save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm trying to create a simple signal which creates an identifier for the model.

```
class Scheduler(models.Model):
    weekhours = models.ManyToManyField('WeekHour', related_name='schedulers')
    identificator = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

class WeekHour(models.Model):
    hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Hour in week (0 - 7*24')
```

Everytime when `Scheduler` object is saved, I want to create or update the `identificator` joining a list of `[weekhour_obj.hour for weekhour_obj in scheduler.weekhours.all()]`

So I created a `post_save` signal. The problem is that when I save `Scheduler`, the signal acts like it was `pre_save`. The `workhours` set for the scheduler is the old one, not updated. When I save it second time it works.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=models.Scheduler)
def set_identificator(sender,created,instance,**kwargs):
    identificator = ','.join([str(x.hour) for x in instance.weekhours.all().order_by('hour')])
    models.Scheduler.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(identificator = identificator)
```

Do you know where is the problem?

EDIT - Example:

When I put `print instance.weekhours.all()` to the first line in the signal method it acts this way:

1. Created a scheduler object in Django admin with weekhours with hour 2 and hour 4. 
   It printed nothing.
2. Opened scheduler in admin and changed WeekHours from 2 and 4 to 5.
   It printed `<QuerySet [<WeekHour: 2>,<WeekHour: 4>]>`
3. Opened scheduler again and changed weekhours to 6 and 7.
   It printed `<QuerySet [<WeekHour: 5>]>`

But it is a `post_save` signal so why it acts like it was `pre_save`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Many-to-many` relationships require the parent object to be saved first , You can’t associate items with a `Scheduler` instance  until it’s been saved.

In your example you are trying to get `instance.weekhours.all()` in `post_save` but it will return always `None` in the first `save`. for that you need to do another save to get values.

You can use [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) instead of `post_save` to create the identificator